# How to map an array inside an array in UseEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Below image will be the response I get from useEffect

[image]

My useEffect will look like this:

```
useEffect(() => {

    const getStatesData = async () => {
      await fetch ('http://localhost:3001/covid19')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        const dataStates = data.states
        const states = dataStates.map((state2) => (
          {
            name: state2.name,
            total: state2.total
          }
        ));
          setStates(states)
      })
    }

    getStatesData();
  }, []);
```

I'm trying to get `name` and `total` inside `districts`, how can I do that?

I've tried using adding `districts: state2.districts` in useEffect, and adding `{state.districts.map(({name, total}) => ({name} ))}` directly in the `<div>` but it's returning an error: `Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {name}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

---

I'm currently using material-ui to help me get thigs easier, here is my full code excluding the useEffect:

```
<div className="App">
      {states.map(state => (
            <Accordion expanded={expanded === state.name}
            <AccordionSummary
              expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
              aria-controls="panel1bh-content"
              id="panel1bh-header"
            >
              <Typography className={classes.heading}>{state.name} ({state.total}) </Typography>
            </AccordionSummary>
            <AccordionDetails>
              <Typography>
              
               !! DISTRICTS NAME HERE (DISTRICTS TOTAL HERE) !!

              </Typography>
            </AccordionDetails>
          </Accordion>
          ))}
    </div>
```

Comment: @AkshayBande I've edited my question with something that I've tried

Comment: @charlietfl can you elaborate more on that please?

Comment: You should however add the expected output, since your current output is flat.

Comment: I think I misread "districts" in the text as "distincts" which would imply merging and summing. With that said you aren't using the `districts` property in your mapping

Comment: @trincot hello, I've just edited my question

Comment: here's an image of what exactly i'm trying to achieve, https://prnt.sc/173go1v . Here is what I got so far https://prnt.sc/173gwik

Comment: @charlietfl I've tried adding `districts` into userEffect, then use mapping inside the `<Typography>` . But it's returning an error

Comment: I don't think you need the map() in the fetch at all. Just do `setStates(data.states)` then do another districts map() inside `<Typography>` to render each district

Comment: @charlietfl you're right, I don't need map() in the fetch! thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of mapping districts like this:

```
{state.districts.map(({name, total}) => ({name} ))}
```

do it like this:

```
{state.districts.map(({name, total}) => `${name} (${total})`)}
```

or even better to a component like this:

```
{state.districts.map(({name, total}) => <div>{name} ({total})<div>)}
```

within the `Typography` component.

The reason being, the mapping `state.districts.map(({name, total}) => ({name} ))` returns an object for each district, and React doesn't recognizes objects as renderable components.

Comment: got it! Thank you so much!